# Which collection type suits my needs the best?

Tags: .net, caching

I have a simple 'caching' infrastructure that looks a bit like follows:

```
Dictionary<string, object> cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

(I'm using `object` as the value type here, but in reality it's a more specific type.)

The idea is to store a number of computed values (actually, results from a SQL database) in tis dictionary by name. I need to do fast inserts and retrievals, mostly for single elements.

Now that it is used, I find that sometimes there's a need to invalidate some entries by removing all that **start with** a specific string. My naive implementation does something like this:

```
cache.Keys.Where(key => key.StartsWith(name)).ToList().ForEach(cache.Remove);
```

Knowing that it's probably not the best solution, I'm looking around in the .NET Framework to find a data structure that allows me to do this more efficiently.

Is there a class that would be a better fit than `Dictionary<>`?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server have you checked out `SqlCacheDependency`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx

Comment: How many items are you expecting in the cache?

Comment: @paul The data itself ultimately comes from SQL Server, but our invalidation is more complex than that.

Comment: @Erno we expect a couple of thousand items in the cache, but very frequent updates and lookups. I'd say 80% lookups, 10% updates and 10% invalidations. But those are rough figures and highly dependenant on usage.

Comment: Are you sure you need the cache? Depending on the setup it might be faster to simply query the database.

Comment: @Erno no, the queries are pretty complicated with multiple inner, outer and cross joins, so the result needs to be cached. Also, it's very likely that the same value is looked up multiple times, for example in the same ASP.NET request.

Comment: (You could cache the query results on the server too) I was just asking because having a cache almost always add complexity (stale data) so I always look for a non-caching solution first, then for a cache someone else built and finaly for a self-made solution.

Comment: (That was our first solution until a client had a setup that resulted in a huge cached table)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find elements that correspond to the start of a string, consider a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). It is effectively a graph (tree) with a letter at each vertex. The code walks the graph starting with one of the roots containing the first letter of the string, moving to the linked node with the corresponding second node and so on.

There is no implementation provided in the base class library. See http://geekyisawesome.blogspot.com.au/2010/07/c-trie.html for a sample implementation.

Comment: We are using a Trie in a different part of our application, so I should have an implementation ready. I'll have a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As akton said, a trie is probably a nice fit. If you want to stick with framework classes you have the following choices:

- Dictionary: O(1) insert, O(1) retrieval, O(n) delete element starting with X
- SortedList: O(log(n)) insert, O(log(n)) retrieval, O(n) delete element starting with X (assuming the number of deleted elements is small compared to number of total elements).

Comment: The documentation for `SortedList<>` states that removal is an O(n) operation. Also, it's internally organized as an array, so a removal of an element should be more costly than with a binary tree, no?